# django - schema migration - how to add a field

Tags: django

I have a django 1.8 app working with a db.
I'm trying to change the schema of a table using the built-in migration.
Here are the steps I did:

In my dev invironment, I grabbed the app source and ran

```
python manage.py sycdb
```

then I ran

```
python manage.py loaddata ~/my_data.json
```

then I modified modes.py. Added a field and renamed a field...all from the same table '**TABLE1**' which had no data.

then

```
python manage.py makemigrations myapp
python manage.py migrate
```

Error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "myapp_someother_table" already exists

then ran

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

worked!
but when I browsed to the admin page for **TABLE1**, I get this error:

OperationalError: no such column: myapp_table1.my_new_field_id

I checked the db and yes, there is no such column.
How can I procceed from here? I prefer to fix this via django.
If I fix it straight in the db, then the migration goes out of sync.

Comment: `python manage.py sy**n**cdb`, what django version anyways?

Comment: I'm using django 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations do not automagically see that you have made changes. Migrations detect changes by comparing the current model with the historical model saved in the migration files.

In this case, you didn't have any historical models, since you didn't have any migrations. Django was not able to detect any changes in your models, even though they were different from your database.

The correct way to make changes to your model is to **first** run `manage.py makemigration <my_app>`, and **then** make the changes to your model, followed by another `manage.py makemigrations`.

Comment: right. The migration directory makes sense now. Do you know what the migration table is for and what would be the consequences of deleting that table?

Comment: The `django_migrations` table records which migrations are applied. If you delete it, django will try to apply each migration again.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to do it via pure django **and** keep your data. I don't have personal experience with [**south**](http://south.aeracode.org/) but there are a lot of mentions if this tool. Just in case if nothing else works for you...

Comment: South had been integrated into django's core migration which is what I'm using. I do not see any reason for trying to load south unless someone has see a bug in the core migration that is not a bug in south.

Comment: South does not work with Django 1.7+. Also, if you see a bug, you should report it at http://code.djangoproject.com, not avoid it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to make things work, but there must be a better way so please add more answers/comments...

1. I deleted the sqlite db and the migration folder
2. I made the desired changes to model.py
3. ran syncdb
4. ran loaddata to load the json data dump that I had saved previously.
5. just started the dev server